# Mac OS X 10.8: Replacement for Lock/UnlockPixels() for the cocoa applications

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

The Lock/UnlockPixels() functions located in `QD/QDOffScreen.h` under `ApplicationServices` framework has been deprecated for the 64-bit applications in which `Carbon` is not supported. Along with this API, there are also other APIs located in the same header which are also deprecated, for instance, DisposeGWorld() and NewGWorld().

I am working on decarbonizing the application for which the application must compile successfully in 64-bit mode. Although, these APIs are not part of Carbon framework, but they work only on 32-bit mode. Is there any substitute or alternate recommendations from Apple for these APIs in the Cocoa applications?

Comment: don't use quickDraw .. the QuickDraw API has been phased out over the past years. -- anyway: to give a 'recommendation' we have to know/see a lot more

Comment: @Daij-Djan The tasks performed by these APIs are mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/reference/QuickDraw_Ref/QuickDraw_Ref.pdf). Can you tell me how can I accomplish them using non-Carbon APIs?

Comment: don't use anything from that document. Use another API and the need for specific functions isn't there.. for example use OpenGL

Comment: I tried an answer even but there is too little info on the 'goal' ;)

Comment: Port your QuickDraw code to Quartz 2D : https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/QuickDrawToQuartz2D/QuickDrawToQuartz2D.pdf

Comment: The `lockFocus` and `unlockFocus` methods of `NSImage` are roughly analogous to `LockPixels` and `'UnlockPixels`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *de-carbonizing* your app don't use QuickDraw at all - as mentioned before it is deprecated. You shouldn't even look for 1:1 replacements as the model in Cocoa is quite different.

You should embrace the *Cocoa* way of drawing:
**[Introduction to Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)**

Instead of thinking about GWorlds you could either directly draw to an `NSImage` object, use `NSBitmapImageRep` or other modern approaches.

Comment: Thanks for providing me some directions to approach the problem. Could you also tell me which method should I adopt - `Cocoa drawing` or `Quartz 2D`?

Comment: Really depends on you requirements - I'd recommend to read through Apple's docs and see whether Cocoa offers all you need or whether you need to dive into Quartz.

Comment: Basically, in the application, offscreen images are being drawn, which of course are later shifted on-screen. Does `cocoa` provide some APIs which support off screen drawing or is it no longer an option?

Comment: An `NSImage` can be drawn into (offscreen drawing) as well as drawn from.  At the lower level of Quartz, there are separate objects for drawing into (bitmap context) and drawing from (`CGImageRef`).